# Audio G.A.N.G. - membership & benefits

Tags: gameaudio, game, organization

Ive been think of getting a membership in Audio G.A.N.G.(Game Audio Network Guild) for a while now.

Any members here?

I guess its a good place for game industry networks?

Does this help me in getting a job/career in the game industry?

Audio G.A.N.G. members, kindly share your success or any kind of benefits that you have got being a member at Audio G.A.N.G.

Cheers!!!

Bala.

Answer (score 1):

I've been a member for around 4 or 5 years now and live in Germany but used to travel regularly to Los Angeles for business.

From my experience they do offer some great events (or at least did, last one I attended was at TODD AO in Santa Monica in 2008 or 2009 I think, no idea about more recent ones) and it does connect you with people but most of these are local to the greater L.A. area. Does this help with a career in in the game industry? Everything is possible, it definitely won't hurt.

If you live in the US or better, L.A. and **if** the GANG website gets fixed (it's been buggy for months now, no logins/signups possible) then yes, I think it's absolutely worth it but if you're from oversees and don't travel to the US regularly then no, not worth it until at the very least the website gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Andre, I live in india & not much of a traveler too... perhaps i should buy a small midi controller for that money :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andre, Bala. If your in the U.S then its great and there are plenty of events. However if you are in Europe then there is little to be gained, apart from the odd exchange or discussion with members via the website and there are better sources for that.